# Express-API POST works in Postman but not with AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I want to make an AJAX call in Javascript to my ExpressJS Rest API.

However with Javascript the POST-call does not work.

In Postman the same JSON-data with the same Headers works.

This is the error in js (ajax):

```
cross-origion Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow.Origin' missing)
```

This is the error in node.js:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Cors are enabled.
Headers are set in the AJAX (Content-Type, ...)

API-Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/api/cart', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(true);
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

AJAX-Code:

```
$.ajax({
                  url:"http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/",
                  type:"POST", //First change type to method here
                  headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                  },
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data:{
                    JSON.stringify(cart)
                  },
                  success:function(response) {
                  },
                  error:function(data, data1, data2){
                    console.log(data1);
                    alert("An Error occurred. Try again later");
                  }
              });
```

I expect the post-api be executed with this ajax code.

However this is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: So your request is causing a *“SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0”* error in the server you’re sending the request to? That seems to be the problem you need to fix, right?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Yes exactly this is the problem.

Comment: @sideshowbarker  the response code returned is "400"

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify(cart)`

Comment: @ChrisG you were right.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change you ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
                  url:"http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/",
                  type:"POST", //First change type to method here
                  headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                  },
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: JSON.stringify(cart),
                  success:function(response) {
                  },
                  error:function(data, data1, data2){
                    console.log(data1);
                    alert("An Error occurred. Try again later");
                  }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/",
    type:"POST", //First change type to method here
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
      "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },

    data:{
      "itemId": 1234
    },
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error:function(data, data1, data2){
      console.log(data1);
      alert("An Error occurred. Try again later");
    }
});
```

Replace your ajax code with above code